# Error Uploading Database

Tags: mysql, sql, localhost

I have made a backup of my Wordpress website and I am trying to run it using XAMPP. I have copied the files but when I use the import option to import the database, I am getting the result that 0 queries executed. Please help. Thanks

Comment: what files have you copied, do you mean that you exported the DB?

Answer (score 0):

There are some reasons for this problem, can you tell us more informations?

I advise this:
Your dump (export) is very large --> if you create the dump with PHPMyadmin the timeout on the websever is to small --> broken file. If you export as zip file, open the file and check the sql-dump file in the zip-package.

Solution increase script timeout if possible or export the tables separately.
Sometimes it is faster to export only the structure of db, import it, after this export and import the tables as csv-file.